# How to obtain all (or last few) messages for a failed job in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

In the SQL Server Agent for SQL Server 2005, I have a job that only has one step, which runs a stored procedure.

When the stored procedure runs to completion, it produces about 500 messages (not counting blank lines).

When the job runs, the history always truncates the messages down to a very small sample of what's produced by the stored procedure. This is fine when it succeeds, but is a problem when it fails because the message explaining the failure is usually not included.

For any given step of a failed job, is there a way to get either of the following?
- All messages; or
- The last few messages, which should include failure details.

I notice all the messages I can see in the job history are warnings with the detail "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation", which can be ignored for this stored procedure. Might there be a way to make the history only include more severe errors and omit warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as making the history only include more severe errors and omit warnings I don't have a solution for you... however in order to include the entire message:

I would go to the Advanced section of the job.

Select "On failure: Quit the job reporting failure" and either select the "output file" option to spit it out to a file, or the "log to table" option.

Either of those shouldn't truncate to 1024 like the history logging does.

Comment: I've used the "output file" option, and that is giving me enough information. Note that both logging options are in the step rather than the job.